# yarn add mangoose

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, yarnpkg

when I wanted install mangoose by yarn command, there is the problem:
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/mangoose: Not found".

Answer (score 1):

You probably mean `mongoose` instead of `m__a__ngoose` (notice the `a` instead of an `o`)

https://npmjs.com/mongoose